# Printing in c program with delay?

Tags: c, exit

I'm trying to print something like:
Exiting...
into a terminal when the program ends, but the way I want it to be outputted to the terminal is each dot after "Exiting" needs to be printed with a slight delay after each other in the same line. Like it is loading to put it that way. But I have no idea how to make it print each of them separately without the whole line to be printed all at the same time. I'm mot sure if that is possible in c in the first place.
I've tried adding delay between each printf using time but that did not work.

Comment: *I've tried adding delay between each `printf` using time but that did not work.* - show the code. You might want to `fflush(stdout)` after each print.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Sounds like a very annoying "feature".

Comment: I fixed it using sleep(); and fflush(stdout) thanks!

Comment: Printing... I think printing is working with printer and you want to show text on screen. And why `exit` tag - because your message is Exiting?

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this -

```
cout<<"Exiting";

cout.flush();
for (int j=0;j<1;j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << ".";
        cout.flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
    cout << "\b\b\b   \b\b\b";
}
cout<<"\n\n";
sleep(1);
```

I was stuck with the same problem where I had to print something with delay.
This thing works flawlessly.

P.S - Use the required Header Files.